# What happens when multiple instances of an application access the same file with StreamWriter at the exact same time?

Tags: c#, .net, file, authentication, streamwriter

I have an application that can be used by multiple users at the once.  The application uses an API and its tokens need to be refreshed from time to time.  The tokens are saved in a file.  When the tokens need to be refreshed, the file is overwritten with the new tokens.  My worry is that it is possible, in rare circumstances, that two instances of the application will try to write to the file at the exact same time.  What happens then?  I want to avoid a situation in which I am left with an empty file.

I have read other related questions and I've seen "the OS will schedule them" and "anything can happen".  Which one is it?

Here are the 5 lines in question if it helps.  Also, this currently isn't happening on a separate thread.

```
string newTokens = GetTokens();
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("TokensFile.txt")) {
    writer.Write(newTokens));
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: You aren't in control of the situation, so put the code block into a try-catch and react to an exception if the writing didn't work.

Comment: I would use a database for that, it's better protected against overwriting. Your current code can certainly overwrite changes made from other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file will have whatever the last writer wrote to it. Giving the writer `FileShare.ReadWrite` will allow multiple writers to use it:

```
string newTokens = GetTokens();
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("TokensFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Readwrite)) {
    writer.Write(newTokens));
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `FileShare.Read` or even `FileShare.None` may be preferable if only one instance should be allowed to have exclusive write access until it closes the file. The other ones will fail, so you'll need to put them in a try-catch. (e.g. when multiple instances running simultaneously receive the exact same tokens, and *at least* one of them needs to save it in a file without stepping on the others' toes). The use case isn't 100% clear from the question.

Comment: Yeah I agree, just handle IOExceptions appropriately

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have a critical section that ensures that only one of your application instance accesses the file at a time. You can do this by using a Mutex as they can be defined to be machine wide and so shared between different processes.

On start up your application will create/open the Mutex. Then when you need to access the file you wait for mutex to be captured, do your file work and then release the mutex. If your application crashes the operating system automatically releases the mutex. So it is nice and safe as well as easy to use.